# Does LIpschitz condition implies boundedness by its constant?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a locally Lipschitz function such that $\rho:[t_{0}, t_{1}] \to \mathbb{R}$ is the unique solution of the p.v.i defined by
$$ \begin{cases}
\rho'(t) & = g(\rho(t)) \\
\rho(t_{0}) & = \rho_{0}
\end{cases}. $$
Defining $L := Lip(g\vert_{[t_{0}, M]})$ where $M:= \max_{t \in [t_{0}, t_{1}]}(\rho(t))$, can we say that $\vert \rho'(t) \vert \leq L \vert \rho(t) \vert$? Is obvious that $\rho'(t)$ is bounded, but is that bound correct?

Comment: You get trivialities like that the solution is continuously differentiable, so that $ρ'(t)$ is bounded as a continuous function on a compact interval. And you get counter examples like $y'=y^2$, $y(0)=1$ that is unbounded in value and derivative on the domain $[0,1)$. So what is it that you really want to know?

Answer (score 1):

If $$R=\max_{t\in[t_0,t_1]}\|ρ(t)-ρ_0\|$$ and $L$ is a Lipschitz constant on $\bar B(ρ_0,R)$, then indeed you get a bound from the Lipschitz condition, but it should look like
$$
\|ρ'(t)\|\le \|f(ρ_0)\|+L\|ρ(t)-ρ_0\|\le \|f(ρ_0)\|+LR.
$$
Per the Grönwall theorem a bound on the solution evolution follows,
$$
\|ρ(t)-ρ_0\|\le \|f(ρ_0)\|\frac{e^{Lt}-1}L.
$$